# XSLT: Applying a template with data from an ancestor's sibling node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm new to both *XPath* and *XSLT* and I'm converting an XML document into another XML document using XSLT.

The following code shows a part of the source document:

```
<aggregateRoot>
   <orderRequest someAttribute="stuff">
       <!--more nodes-->
   </orderRequest>
   <order>
      <item>
        <template>
          <node>
             <image/>
          </node>
        </template>
      </item>
    </order>
<aggregateRoot>
```

Here's what my XSLT looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!--A bunch of stuff that works already-->   
   <Orders>
      <xsl:for-each select="aggregateRoot/order">
         <!--More Nodes-->
         <xsl:for-each select="item/template">
             <Jobs>
                 <xsl:apply-templates select="//agregateRoot/orderRequest"/>   <!--PROBLEM AREA-->
             </Jobs>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </Orders>
<xsl:template/>

<xsl:template match="aggregateRoot/orderRequest">
   <!--Grab data from orderRequest and its children-->
</xsl:template>
```

**Problem description:**

In the XSLT above, when I'm inside the `<Jobs>` node, I'm trying to apply a template based on the `<orderRequest>` node, which is a sibling of the `<order>` node and a child of the main `<aggregateRoot>` node.

I've tried dozens of combinations to change the structure of both the `select` and `match` statements, but I can't access the `<orderRequest>` node or even get the second template to fire.

Comment: _"I can't seem to get what I want."_ What is it that you want? Can you show us the expected output? Your template for `orderRequest` is empty, so it's not going to do anything.

Comment: The contents of the `orderRequest` node aren't too important, but lets say for the moment that I want my template to grab the value `someAttribute`.  But for now I'd be happy with just accessing the `orderRequest` node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems with your XSLT and two smaller issues:

- It is not well formed (neither is your sample input)
- You have misspelled "aggregate"
- You are using a double slash where you only need a single one
- You are overusing `for-each` instead of templates

Once the first two problems are fixed, the XSLT works. Here it is with all 4 issues fixed:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Orders>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="aggregateRoot/order" />
    </Orders>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="order">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="item/template" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="template">
    <Jobs>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/aggregateRoot/orderRequest"/>
    </Jobs>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="orderRequest">
    <xsl:value-of select="@someAttribute" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This produces the output:

```
<Orders>
  <Jobs>stuff</Jobs>
</Orders>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  The main document and the input are well formed and are much larger than what I wanted to post.  I copied and pasted some parts out so that probably broke the documents. 

I'll convert to Templates instead of for-each, thank you much!